# how to fix overfitting or where is my fault in my code

Tags: python, keras

I'm using a pre-trained model Vgg16 to do 100 classification problem. The dataset is tiny-imagenet, each class has 500 images, and I random choose 100 class from tiny-imagenet for my training(400) and validation(100) data. So I change input_shape of vgg16 for 32*32 size.
The results always look like overfitting. Training acc is high, but val_acc always stuck at almost 40%.
I used dropout, regularization L2, data augmentation ... , but val_acc is also stuck at almost 40%.
How could I do for overfitting or correct my code.
Thanks

```
img_width, img_height = 32, 32

epochs = 50

learning_rate = 1e-4

steps_per_epoch = 2500

train_path='./training_set_100A/'

valid_path='./testing_set_100A/'

test_path='./testing_set_100A/'

class_num = 100


train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255
                ,rotation_range=20, zoom_range=0.15,
                width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,     
shear_range=0.15,
                horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest"
                ).flow_from_directory(
                train_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height),     
batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(
                valid_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height),     
batch_size=10, shuffle=False)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(
test_path, target_size=    
(img_width,img_height),batch_size=10,shuffle=False)


seqmodel = Sequential()

VGG16Model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

input = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3), name='image_intput')

output_vgg16_conv = VGG16Model(input)

x = Flatten()(output_vgg16_conv)

x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Dense(class_num, activation='softmax')(x)

funcmodel = Model([input], [x])

funcmodel.summary()    

funcmodel.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9), 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_history = funcmodel.fit_generator(train_batches, 
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, validation_data=valid_batches, 
validation_steps=1000, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

`

Comment: hello, you can try to reduce the complexity of your model, maybe 4096 for your dense layers is a bit too high.

Comment: @AdForte oh, I'm sorry , I forget to add change dense neurons(4096 to 2048, 1024, ..to 128), but val_acc not too much change

Comment: then the val_acc is due to the size of your training set, which is maybe a little too low

Comment: But i think that model is maybe too complex, have you tried a simpler custom keras model?

Comment: @AdForte  thanks for your suggestions. Are there any bug in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you followed examples of implementing this from other sites, but you're training samples are very small to train the 2 new Dense layers of 4096 size each.
you have to either lower the size of you layers or add a lot more samples 20,000 instead of 500.

Comment: you mean my dataset is not good for vgg16 to train. if i still use this dataset how many dense neurons you suggest ? or where can I imporove? I have no idea . thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) 50epoch is too much. Try running smaller epoch?

2) Check your validation accuracy for every epoch?

3) VGG is too deep for your small(32 * 32) image data. Try building your own network with lesser number of parameters. or Try Lenet?

Comment: I run 50 epochs, but I check val_acc every epoch . It always stuck at 40%.
So maybe vgg16 is not good for 32*32 size image?  thanks

Comment: @ricky. Yes your model is over parameterised, which will cause overfitting in usual case. It could be that your data size is insufficient to have unbiased estimate of parameters. Using augmentation will help the model to better guess the parameters

Comment: I don't have others dataset like this. or can i use ImageDataGenerator to resize to 224*224 to train, but I think it is odd.
or how many dense neurons you suggest. do you have others choice except change model. thank you very much.

Comment: @ricky I think it is very likely a model problem. Upscaling image is not gonna give you any advantage as you are simply duplicating information. My advice is try using "Lenet".